# How to show text likt this in Chartjs Dougnet chart

Tags: charts, chart.js

How can I add text in slices in Chartjs doughnet charts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ljnW.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default this is not possible in chart.js, you can use the datalabels plugin to achieve what you want

https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html